# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.sparse'

Tags: python, anaconda

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Dell\.spyder-py3\SPYDER PROGRAMMING\temp.py", line 54, in <module>
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

  File "C:\Users\Dell\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 82, in <module>
    from .base import clone

  File "C:\Users\Dell\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .utils import _IS_32BIT

  File "C:\Users\Dell\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from scipy.sparse import issparse

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.sparse'
```

I have scipy in "conda list -n base" so i have no clue how to solve this

Comment: maybe it needs to install some other module. OR maybe you have file `scipy.py` or folder `scipy` and now `import` try to find `sparse` in your file/folder and it can't find it - it need to rename file/folder.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).